# Counting primitive integer solutions for a given primitive pythagorean triplet $x^2+y^2=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $(x,y,z)$ be a primitive pythagorean triplet, that is $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$ and $x^2+y^2=z^2$, and consider the finite number : $$N= \#\{(a,b)\mid a^2+b^2=z^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \gcd(a,b,z)=1\}$$

I suspect that $N$ can take only two values $N \in \{0, 1\}$

Examples

$13^2+84^2=85^2$ and $36^2+77^2=85^2$ 
$16^2+63^2=65^2$ and $33^2+56^2=65^2$ 
Can anyone help with a solution to this question ?
Thanks

Comment: I suppose you mean $N\in\{1,2\}$, as $85^2$ has already two coprime representations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample with $N=4$ different coprime ways.

\begin{align}
9425^2 & = 776^2+9393^2,\\
       & = 1233^2+9344^2,\\
       & = 5704^2+7503^2,\\
       & = 6063^2+7216^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I beleive it should interensting to study the magnitude of that number $N$ wjith $z$  large enough

Comment: @HassanB If you think that this example is helpful, you can accept this answer. Yes, the number can be studied, because we know a formula for $r_2(n)$, e.g., see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536097/representing-a-given-number-as-the-sum-of-two-squares).

Answer (score 0):

$N = \#\big\{ (a,b): a^2+b^2 \leq z^2, \, \gcd(a,b)=1\}$ can be given by
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\sqrt {z^2-1}} \sum_{\substack{1\le b\le \sqrt{z^2-a^2} \\ \gcd(a,b)=1 \\ a\not\equiv b\pmod2}} 1$$
Read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218647/restricted-totient-sums-sum-n-1-sqrt-l-1-widehat-varphib-n-n/3218807#3218807) for further explanation. I hope this helps!